# URL Rewriting http to https

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Having trouble with a rewrite rule in .htaccess file for WordPress site. The regex and rule I have used in the past on multiple sites is failing me in this case.  Here is what I have used many times successfully:

```
# Force https for all form URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^page https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The goal is to route every request for the WP form at:

```
http://domain.com/folder/payment-page/
```

... to the https version:

```
https://domain.com/folder/payment-page/
```

This works 100% of the time, if the URL does not have a folder/subfolder (or hypen "-") in it. For example,  `http://domain.com/page/` routes as expected on the 4 sites I've done this with.

The question is, what edit do I need to make to the match string/regex to successfully route requests for:

```
http://domain.com/folder/payment-page/
```

to the https version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in this case

```
# Force https for all CC URLs
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443 [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^folder/payment-page/?$ https://domain.com/folder/payment-page/ [R=301,L]
```